# Python multiprocess/multithreading in database driven scraping

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have around `7 lacs` website url in my database. I just scraping some short info form that website.

But when I run the scripting, it is normal to take huge to time to check such a huge URLs.

Currently, is am doing with for loop:

```
def scrape_short_webinfo():
    # a function scraping some minor data

for instance in Link.objects.all():
    scrape_short_webinfo(instance.url)
```

I want to put these thing in multiprocess/multipthread, so that it the script should finish more faster.

Can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: You could just use scrapy to scrape the website

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExecutorService to parallelize your code